# Writing multiple lines to a file in Lua

Tags: mysql, lua, lua-table

I try to write multiple lines to a file in Lua but I don't get how to do it. I tried this:

```
local category = io.open("/usr/home/game/share/locale/germany/category.txt", "w")
category:write(mysql_query("USE account; SELECT DISTINCT itemshop_categories.category AS a, itemshop_categories.id AS b FROM itemshop INNER JOIN itemshop_categories ON itemshop.category_id = itemshop_categories.id ORDER BY itemshop.category_id ASC;"))
category:close()
```

mysql_query gives me a table like this

```
{
{"1_1", "1_2"},
{"2_1", "2_2"},
{"3_1", "3_2"}
}
```

so I want to write this to the .txt file but it doesn't work.
And if I get it to work, will I be able to read this file like this:

```
local category = io.open("/usr/home/game/share/locale/germany/category.txt", "r")
category:read()[2][1]
category:close()
```

to get "2_1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly write a table to a file. You have to serialize it. If you serialize it correctly you can then just load the file back as lua code to get an identical table as a result.

Writing a simple table serializer is not complicated. Writing a robust one is a fair bit harder. Luckily the fine folks on the lua-users.org wiki have written a number of such serialization mechanisms (of varying quality and feature support).

Find one that suits your purposes. http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Comment: thanks, I found that too.
I implemented the SaveTableToFile function to my libary und tried to get information of it like that:
    say(table.load("/usr/home/game/share/locale/germany/quest/Ingame_Itemshop/category.lua").a[1])

(say is like print)
but it doesnt work ...

Comment: How does it not work? What's `.a` there? Your example didn't have a named key. What do you get back from `table.load`? What's in `category.lua`?

Comment: it was just a simple problem ... i forgot the enter the new function-names to the list of quest_functions which is needed to use them. it works fine now. thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse the table returned by `mysql_query` and write its contents by hand:

```
for k,v in ipairs(mysql_query("USE account; SELECT DISTINCT itemshop_categories.category AS a, itemshop_categories.id AS b FROM itemshop INNER JOIN itemshop_categories ON itemshop.category_id = itemshop_categories.id ORDER BY itemshop.category_id ASC;")) do
 category:write(k,"\t",v,"\n")
end
```

To read it back, you read the file line by line (possibly using `io.lines`), split each line into two fields, and process the fields as desired.